# Как вывести слова в порядке, обратном лексикографическому

Tags: python

Необходимо вывести слова по частоте появления в тексте (сначала самые частые), а если слова имеют одинаковую частоту, то нужно вывести их в порядке, обратном лексикографическому.

```
document_text = 'There are the Food Courts in the cities that seats a lot of people and caters for every taste with dishes from all around the world. The aromatic smells that come from the Food Courts arc so delicious that your mouth will water. In recent years foreign foods have become a regular part of our life.'
s = document_text.replace(".", " ").lower().split()
def word_frequency(s):
    words = {}
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        item = s[i]
        count = s.count(item)
        words[item] = count
    print(sorted(words.items(), key = lambda item : item[1], reverse=True))
    return 0
print(word_frequency(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто используйте следующий ключ при сортировке:

```
print(sorted(words.items(), key = lambda item : (item[1], item[0]), reverse=True))
```

Т.е. будут сортироваться кортежи `(частота, "слово")`.

Answer (score 0):

Два изменения: используется [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) и сортируется результат сперва по счетчику, затем по слову. Результат сортировки переворачивается задом-наперед что приводит к нужному результату: сперва идут большие счетчики, затем маленькие. Если значения счетчиков одинаковы, то слова идут в обратном лексикографическом порядке:

```
import collections


document_text = 'There are the Food Courts in the cities that seats a lot of people and caters for every taste with dishes from all around the world. The aromatic smells that come from the Food Courts arc so delicious that your mouth will water. In recent years foreign foods have become a regular part of our life.'
s = document_text.replace(".", " ").lower().split()
c = collections.Counter(s)
print(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda item: item[::-1], reverse=True))
```

> ```
> $ python count-and-sort.py 
> [('the', 5), ('that', 3), ('of', 2), ('in', 2), ('from', 2), ('food', 2),
> ('courts', 2), ('a', 2), ('your', 1), ('years', 1),
> ('world', 1), ('with', 1), ('will', 1), ('water', 1), ('there', 1),
> ('taste', 1), ('so', 1), ('smells', 1), ('seats', 1), ('regular', 1),
> ('recent', 1), ('people', 1), ('part', 1), ('our', 1), ('mouth', 1),
> ('lot', 1), ('life', 1), ('have', 1), ('foreign', 1), ('for', 1),
> ('foods', 1), ('every', 1), ('dishes', 1), ('delicious', 1), ('come',
> 1), ('cities', 1), ('caters', 1), ('become', 1), ('around', 1),
> ('aromatic', 1), ('are', 1), ('arc', 1), ('and', 1), ('all', 1)]
> ```